# Custom Function for Portfolio Archive Template With Conditonal Tag

Tags: conditional-tags

Can't work out which conditional tag to use to add a page title to the portfolio archive page which uses custom posts types.

This doesn't work:

```
if( is_archive('portfolio') )
echo '<div class="portfolio-title">Add Your Page Title Here</div>';
};
```

// Here's the code which generates the portfolio post type and archive

```
add_action( 'init', 'executive_portfolio_post_type' );
function executive_portfolio_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'portfolio',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Portfolio', 'executive' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio', 'executive' ),
        ),
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/icons     /portfolio.png',
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio' ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes', 'genesis-seo' ),
    )
);
```

}

// Or maybe its something which needs to added in the portfolio archive template

```
function executive_portfolio_grid() {
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){
    echo '<div class="portfolio-featured-image">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() .'" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'portfolio' );
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

}

Comment: That works for the portfolio posts, not the portfolio archive page. I only need to add a title to the portfolio archive page which lists the portfolio posts in the archives. Not the posts themselves.

Comment: I got this working by changing the hook as it didn't work when using the post title hook which displayed the archives page title on all posts attached to the custom post type.

Answer (score 1):

Use `is_post_type_archive()`:

```
if ( is_post_type_archive( 'portfolio' ) )
{
    // echo something
}
```

You can also pass multiple post types here:

```
if ( is_post_type_archive( array ( 'portfolio', 'project' ) ) )
{
    // echo something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`is_archive()` is a boolean function and it just checks whether it's an archive page or not and that archive page can be for a Category, Tag, Author, Date, Custom Post Type or Custom Taxonomy.

You can use `is_post_type_archive()` function to check current is an archive of that post type you are looking for. This function accepts array and string values so for your case you can use:

```
if( is_post_type_archive('portfolio') )
   echo '<div class="portfolio-title">Add Your Page Title Here</div>';
};
```